# In Python, when I call multiprocessing.Manager() ,console tell me that "module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When I use multiprocessing.Manager() like this

```py
def run_main(userdata):
    print("main begin")
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        for vehicle in Dao.vehicle_dictionary.values():
            trajectory = Dao.get_trajectory_by_id(vehicle.id)
            shared_memory = manager.list([vehicle, trajectory])  # index 0 is vehicle，index 1 is trajectory
            new_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=update_location(), args=(shared_memory[0], shared_memory[1]))
            new_process.start()
```

the console tell me  "AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'"

```
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'

At:
  C:\PanoSim5\Bin\py36\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py(163): get_preparation_data
  C:\PanoSim5\Bin\py36\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py(33): __init__
  C:\PanoSim5\Bin\py36\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py(322): _Popen
  C:\PanoSim5\Bin\py36\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py(105): start
  C:\PanoSim5\Bin\py36\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py(513): start
  C:\PanoSim5\Bin\py36\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py(56): Manager
  C:/PanoSimDatabase/Plugin/Traffic\package_runservice\RunService.py(30): run_main
  C:/PanoSimDatabase/Plugin/Traffic\Demogg.py(27): ModelOutput
```

Is there any master can tell me what happend

[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8zMU.png)
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqb1v.png)

Comment: no links or images please, please paste as formatted text/code

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please provide your source code as [markdown-formatted code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), no images or external links please. also, have you tried isolating the problem by debugging your code?

Comment: I click "Attach to Process" in Pycharm, but it can't catch the exceptions

Comment: Can you extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, make sure the error output from running it is included. There's lots of unknowns without that at the moment. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @MapleWolf sometimes IDE's get in the way of how the language is supposed to work... running your code from cmd with `>python.exe myscript.py` will give output in the most consistent way possible (and it's easy to copy and paste the text).

Comment: as for what's causing the error... one of the libraries you're using must modify the sys module.. That's quite bad practice, but a simple fix could simply be to re-set `sys.argv` back to something simple like an empty list after your imports.

Comment: Does multiprocessing have to be inside the main function？

Comment: *"Does multiprocessing have to be inside the main function?"* This is a vague question whose meaning I will guess. If you are running under Windows (you did not specify your platform as you are supposed to but I can infer Windows from your paths), then any code that creates new processes needs to be invoked within an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. So if you have `if __name__ == '__main__': run_main(data)`, that should be okay.